# Cannot run Appium test on Jenkin with AppiumDriverLocalService

Tags: jenkins, appium

I can run appium test with AppiumDriverLocalService in my local PC but i cannot run it on Jenkin

Error log : 
[ERROR] Tests run: 286, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 285, Time elapsed: 2.911 s <<< FAILURE! - in TestSuite
[ERROR] BeforeClass(chat.Chat)  Time elapsed: 2.033 s  <<< FAILURE!
io.appium.java_client.service.local.InvalidServerInstanceException: Invalid server instance exception has occured: The invalid appium node C:\windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\build\lib\main.js has been defined
Caused by: java.io.IOException: The node C:\windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\build\lib\main.jsdoesn't exist

```
    AppiumServiceBuilder builder = new AppiumServiceBuilder();
    builder.usingDriverExecutable(new File(NODE_JS_PATH));
    builder.withAppiumJS(new File(APPIUM_JS_PATH));
    builder.usingAnyFreePort();

    AppiumDriverLocalService service = AppiumDriverLocalService.buildService(builder);
    service.start();
    service.getUrl();

    DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
    caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM, platformName);
    caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, platformVersion);
    caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, usingDeviceId);
    caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.UDID, usingDeviceId);
    caps.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.CHROMEDRIVER_EXECUTABLE, System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/src/test/java/resources/chromedriver.exe");
    caps.setCapability("unicodeKeyboard", "true");
    caps.setCapability("appPackage", appPackage);
    caps.setCapability("appActivity", appActivity);
    caps.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.NATIVE_WEB_SCREENSHOT, true);
    caps.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.AUTO_GRANT_PERMISSIONS, true);

    driver = new AndroidDriver(service, caps);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(timeDefault, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the error indicates that Appium installation on Jenkins node is absent or corrupt.

You need to install pretty much everything you have locally in order to be able to run Appium tests in Jenkins to wit:

1. [Appium](http://appium.io/docs/en/about-appium/getting-started/)
2. [Android SDK](https://developer.android.com/studio)
3. Define [`ANDROID_HOME` environment variable](https://www.360logica.com/blog/how-to-set-path-environmental-variable-for-sdk-in-windows/) pointing to the Android SDK installation root and amend Windows [PATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) to include `tools` and `platform-tools` folder
4. The Appium environment integrity can be checked using [appium-doctor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/appium-doctor) package

You can also check out [Appium - Code Examples - Java - Chrome on Android Test using Java](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TE/Java) for sample code of Appium-based browser test

Comment: I implemented number 1,2,3 but 4 i not used to before that. I can run test in local but error on Jenkin. Can you tell me more about how to install a node on jenkin, or give me a reference link. Many thanks